# Is anything known about Saitama's family?

Tags: one-punch-man

I've watched season 1 and 2 of the anime, read part of the manga, read part of the webcomic and watched at least some OVAs (not sure they were all of them). I dont remember anything said or shown about Saitama's family. Is anything known about them? Also , aside of those sources, I know there are audiobooks, that there is an official encyclopedia, and that sometimes the author and the artist answer questions from the fans in an "official" way.

Is anything known about Saitama's family?

Answer (score 1):

To this date, we have no info on Saitama's family. Not even in the webcomic. However, there is a big controversy/theory about this and that is:

Spoiler from manga/webcomic:

> Blast, number 1 hero, being a relative of Saitama. However as I said, this is a fan theory.

Comment: Out of curiosity has anyone summarized any evidence for the fan theory or is that one of those wishful thinking ones?

Comment: Well, there is no real evidence but some convenient ones for the sake of the theory.

Comment: @kaine Both consider being a hero to be a hobby and both wear a cape and a jumpsuit with a front zipper is basically all there is.  So wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no information about the family of your beloved one punch man.
Even in the manga no information of such kind has been disclosed up until now. But i really hope in the upcoming chapter there will be some disclosure about his family background.

Answer (score 1):

So far there is still no information regarding about Saitama's family. The webcomic did not mentioned a thing about his family and is probably something the fans must be quite curious about till this day.The only thing we could do now is to wait and see how the author is going to progress with the story line.